# OpenCV giving an opposite color order (BGR - RGB) upon reading

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, color-channel

According to the official documentation, reading an image using opencv decodes an in BGR order. But using the version (opencv-python==4.7.0.72), its returning the image in RGB order in a default mode.

```
import cv2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_path = '/home/dell/Downloads/God_Ganesha.jpg'

    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    cv2.namedWindow('cv2 bgr', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('cv2 bgr', image)
    cv2.namedWindow('cv2 rgb', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('cv2 rgb', img_rgb)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Reading an image using opencv should have returned the image in BGR order (official doc) but it's returning in RGB order, and when I did cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, it returned in BGR order. Opencv has not mentioned that their default has been changed into RGB. Is there anything I am missing here or error?

[image: Screenshot of the image on both color order]

Comment: Opencv reads images in BGR and alle the functions that use color (imshow, imsrite, etc.) assume BGR ordering.

Comment: OpenCV reads images and holds them internally in BGR format. Its `cv2.imshow()` equally expects images in BGR format. So it is entirely consistent within itself.

Comment: Why tag that C++? All of your code shown here is `python` code...

Comment: Thank for the answers. That means while changing the color space to HSV, we can simply do cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV right? without thinking about RGB. I was experimenting RGB2HSV and BGR2HSV and results were different.

Comment: yes, after reading from a file, use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV`. You should then see the same results as when you first use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB` followed by a `cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read , show image in open cv to cv you do not need to convert to RGB format.
But if you want to read CV and show in Matplotlib , Pillow then you have to convert to RGB